# CSS split bar graph with solid border radius

Tags: border, css

I'm trying to let a div container with a black background substitute as the border style for a bar graph that has a border radius.  Here's the HTML/CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="graph-outer">
    <div class="inner-left-cap"></div>
    <div class="inner-left-bar">40%</div>
    <div class="inner-right-bar">60%</div>
    <div class="inner-right-cap"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.graph-outer {
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;   
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.inner-left-cap {
    background: orange;
    width: 2%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.inner-left-bar {
    background: orange;
    width: 38%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-cap {
    background: red;
    width: 2%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-bar {
    background: red;
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/115/

The issue in which I am having is that the corners don't look as if they have any black border style whatsoever.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this version with overflow:hidden and a explicit border on your outer controller and no padding.

```
.graph-outer {
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;   
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.inner-left-cap {
    background: orange;
    width: 2%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.inner-left-bar {
    background: orange;
    width: 38%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-cap {
    background: red;
    width: 2%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-bar {
    background: red;
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/116/

Comment: Bah, the explicit border on outer is such a no-brainer.  Guess I was having no brains.

Comment: without overflow:hidden, the rectangular containers inside would destroy the round corners.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your CSS, I changed the caps to 3% each and made the bars smaller. The bar on the inside was going over the caps.

```
.graph-outer {
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;   
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.inner-left-cap {
    background: orange;
    width: 3%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.inner-left-bar {
    background: orange;
    width: 37%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-cap {
    background: red;
    width: 3%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-bar {
    background: red;
    width: 57%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/119/

Answer (score 0):

a solution without the end-caps (that way the bar width matches the values)

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/118/)

the `graph-outer` is 20px tall so the nested bars are 18px (20px - 2px (1px top/bottom padding)), set the border-radius on the bars to 9px each (half of the height so each corner is uniform and matches the parents curvature)

```
.inner-left-bar {
    background: orange;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border-radius:9px 0 0 9px; /* add this */
}

.inner-right-bar {
    background: red;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border-radius:0 9px 9px 0; /* and this */
}

/* and drop the end-caps */
​
```

Comment: Here's why I can't do it that way, as far as I know: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/122/. In this case, when the right bar is 100%, and the left is 0, I'll just fill in the left cap with red to preserve the border radius.

Comment: @keruilin one solution would be to add a 100% class to the bar, like this http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/123/.  Wouldn't a similar issue come up with coloring the end-cap when one of the bars is 98% or higher?

Comment: Yes, I need to address that. :)  Perhaps some right, left padding between the two bars.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/120/

```
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 2px;
```

That should do it! I just threw on a border-radius and bumped up the padding 1. There should be an easier way using the actual border property but im feeling lazy and this does it

Comment: The corners still don't look consistent though. :/

Comment: Don't want to use padding of 2px. Too thick of border.